# How to connect the counter below to the counter above

Tags: clock, flipflop, counter

I am designing a synchronous DOWN counter that is supposed to count down from 20 to 00. I tried many different ways but the logic combinations I tried are obviously wrong as I am getting very weird sequences.
How am I supposed to connect the top counter to the bottom counter? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The logic you have to work out is to enable the top counter to decrement at the time the lower counter is set to decrement and has a current value of 0.

Comment: Generate a CARRy OUT signal (actually a BORROW since it's a down counter, which you connect to an ENABLE input on the top counter (you'll have to work out how to make that too). Clock them both from the same clock to keep them synchronous. You can test the BORROW and ENABLE separately to make testing simpler.